# Analog divider using log and antilog op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, diodes, analog

I'm trying to design an analog divider using log and anti log op-amps but I cannot obtain the desired output value. I want the exact output value like 0.6mA/0.1mA = 6.
My circuit simulation looks like this:

[image]

Is there any suggestion how to fix it?

@JRE Log op-amps gives nagative output as you can see in the image
[image]

Comment: Yes. Start debugging. Test each stage individually, move on when that stage is working.

Comment: Here's a pro-tip: Don't start that transient simulation yet, **ALWAYS** do an operating point (.op) simulation first and **check all the DC voltages and DC currents**. Are they what you expect them to be? No? Then fix that first. Only a properly biased circuit will work so check that. Even after 25 years of designing circuits I sometimes go against my own advice (oh, that will work) and then it doesn't. Which I could have easily spotted if I had bothered to checked all the DC voltages first. Doh!

Comment: @Rahovart:  Compare your antilog circuit to the one [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications#Exponential_output)

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie thanks for your advice, i tested and i thing log and differential op amp parts are working but i cannot figure it out antilog part. Probably too much current flow on diode.

Comment: @JRE i think you want to say my diode reverse connected but output of differential amplifier negative

Comment: Is it? 0.6 - 0.1 is 0.5.  Looks like it ought to be positive to me.

Comment: I think your DC voltages show an issue around D2, R21 and U14. Check the voltage difference at the inverting input of U14. Is it what it should be? To me the voltage at the kathode of D2 looks too low, I would expect around -0.7 V. I suspect that the current through R21, which will also flow through D2, is more than the opamp can handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: log divider]

This circuit calculates (1*0.6)/0.1 = 5.88 = approx 6

The multiplication by 1 is necessary so that the voltage across D3 is in a similar range to those voltages across D1, D2 and D4 which means that the voltage across D3 can be interpreted correctly by the anti-log amp.

IC3 is a non-inverting summing amp (with overall unity gain) but its input from the I1 signal path has been inverted by IC6 so that it presents a signal of the opposite polarity to those from the I2 and I3 signal paths causing it to actually be subtracted when the summation is performed.

I think that the small inaccuracy in the output result can be attributed to non-ideal op amp behaviour such as input offset voltages.

The simulation was performed in Circuit Wizard.

**EDIT**

I managed to simplify our designs by reducing the number of op amps by 1.

This modification feeds the denominator voltage (the factor to be divided by) into the inverting input of the "summer" thereby subtracting it.

This design also has the added advantage that the final output is of the correct polarity (positive).

[image: Modified log divider]

Answer (score 1):

1- Try with input **voltage** rather then current. (0.1V -> R11, 1V -> R6)

*Little exercise : Are inputs "swappable" ? Can you do it ? And how ? What condition ?*

2- **Use same resistors for all**, 10 k for example ...

3- Correct the output gain answer after (R21).

I used LF13741 opamps ... They work admirably in simulation (1m -> 10V inputs).

I even used for the fun (after correcting offsets) LM741... But don't change temperature !

I added also 10 Meg resistors // diodes to be able to adjust OPamp's offsets.

NB : The 3 "diodes" must be "at the same temperature". Some "boards" (IC) had a heater to maintain these "components" @85 °C with a very good thermal regulation.

***Remember that "diode characteristic" (diode or trans-diode) change drastically with T°.***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why are you multiplying by 12.5 after the log?

Multiplying in the log domain is performing an exponentiation operation.

You should divide by 10 at the output or subtract a constant in the log domain.

As others have commented you are using a current input in which case R6 and R11 are not needed (they shouldn't affect the result though).

Diodes such as 1N4148 do not have a very good logarithmic current vs voltage curve. Bipolar transistors connected as diodes ( In the "Transdiode" configuration) are much better. Even better is to use the transistor in the feedback loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your helps.
I handled problem and set up this circuit:
[image]
It's working perfectly.

Comment: See edit to my answer.

Comment: @James oh thanks thats better